# Error in sql syntax with Select SUM

Tags: php, mysql

how do i write this properly?

```
$sql_totalbooknumber =  "SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND `category_id` <>355";
```

i get this

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND `cate' at line 1

```
    if (!mysql_query($sql_totalbooknumber))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  };
```

Comment: How are you executing this query? Having a syntax error at the very start implies you've got something else in front of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try
`$sql_totalbooknumber =  "SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND category_id != 355"`;

Comment: `<>` and `!=` are equivalent. `<>` is the traditional SQL way of expressing non-equivalence.